# Array Manipulation with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema that is essentially an employee and a team. When you update an employee you can change their team. What I want to happen is update the Employee team id and remove that employee from every other team in the database. An employee can only be in one team is a business rule we are enforcing.

These are the abridged schemas I am working with.

### Employee Schema

```
var EmployeeSchema = new Schema({
  id: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  team: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Team'
  }
});
```

### Team Schema

```
var TeamSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  members: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Employee'
  }]
});
```

What I want to happen is when I change an employees team, I want to remove that employee from every teams list of members, update the employee's team reference, and then update the new team's array of members.

### Current code

```
var empMongoID = req.params.id;
Team.update({
  $pull: {
    members: {
      _id:empMongoID
    }
  }
}, {
  multi: true
}, function (err, numberAffected, raw) {
  console.log(err, numberAffected, raw);
  callback(null);
})
```

This does nothing and the log is `null, 0, undefined`.

Comment: Perhaps you should make the relationship go only one way from employee to team? Sure, mongoose won't do the query automatically for you via `populate` for getting employees in a team (you would have for ask for employees with a specific team id using a normal query...you could make this a schema method), but your schema would enforce your "one team only" rule rather than having to do it programmatically. This is how its done in relational databases. IMO, this sort of data is not a good fit for a document database since it is inherently relational.

Comment: I had that thought as well. Once I got started, the current approach seemed counter to the "mongoose way." Any suggestion on how, if I did change the schema around, if I requested a `Team` document, I could get it's members? You mentioned schema method?

Comment: Schema methods: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#methods. Make one on your `Team` schema which returns an array of `Employee`. You can call it after loading your team. (I can post an example later)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, you might want to change your schema so that `Team` does not contain a reference to its employees, leaving the reference only on the `Employee`. This removes the need to programatically "update" the teams to keep the user lists in sync or to construct crazy convoluted update queries.

So, you would get a schema like this:

```
var EmployeeSchema = new Schema({
    id: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    team: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Team'
    }
});
mongoose.Model('Employee', EmployeeSchema)

var TeamSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});

TeamSchema.methods.getEmployees = function (fn) {
    return this.Model('Employee').find({ team: this._id }, fn)
}

mongoose.Model('Team', TeamSchema)
```

To use:

```
var team = ... //load your team somehow
team.getEmployees(function (err, employees) {
    //do something with your list of employees
});
```

The idea here is that your schema enforces the many-to-one relationship between employee and team. An employee can be part of exactly one team by definition in the schema, so all your team needs to do is provide a method to search for employees with a matching team id. The team never directly holds its references.

This is more or less exactly what you would see in a normal relational database as well, so the same ideas can apply when using something like mongoose to give you a "schema" with your non-relational schemaless database (which IMO means you should move to a database with a schema, but mongodb is cool in many ways with its queries and other stuff which could justify its use in a "schema'd" situation).

Comment: So how would I attach the team members to the results? Just attach them to the `Team` model? I basically don't ever want you to get a `Team` without having the members object available.

Comment: This wasn't _exactly_ what I ended up doing, but it send me down the right path and should be able to help the next person. Thank you.